# Yii2 Ajax DropDownList change content of div

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, yii2

I'm developing a application with Yii2 and I don't have to much knowledge of ajax. So I tried to use an example of W3Schools (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

I want to make sort of a filter and I want to change the content of a div using a value from a DropDownList, here is the code of the view:

```
...
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str==="") {

document.getElementById("transactions").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

  document.getElementById("transactions").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
 };    
    xmlhttp.open("GET",document.location.href="filter?by="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
```

Now the DropDownList:

```
<?=Html::dropDownList(
    'test', //name
    'b', //select
    ['' => 'Select Filter...', '1' => 'Exchanging Now', '2' => 'Last Exchanged', '3' => 'Last Offered', '4' => 'Last Discounted', '5' => 'Last Recieved', '6' => 'View All'],
    ['onchange'=> 'showUser(this.value)'])
   ?>
```

Well, the content of the div "transactions" it changes but, the it redirects to localhost/.../filter?by=x

How can I stop this redirect? In my controller I'm returning a string. Is that a problem?

--- EDIT ---

After some research I read about Pjax, I tried some tests and with a simple  link and with works but can't do with the dropdownlist. Here is the changes on my code.
View:

```
<div id="categories">
<?=Html::a('TEST LINK', Url::to(['filter', 'by' => 1]), ['data-pjax' => 'transactions'])
?>
```

```
    <?= Html::dropDownList(
            'test', //name
            'b', //select
            ['' => 'Select Filter...', '1' => 'Exchanging Now', '2' => 'Last Exchanged', '3' => 'Last Offered', '4' => 'Last Discounted', '5' => 'Last Recieved', '6' => 'View All'], //items
            ['onchange' => 'this.form.submit()'], ['data-pjax' => 'transactions']
    )
    ?>
```

[PjaxCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHALP.png)
StackOverflow dont let me put the code of Pjax, so I uploaded an image through a link

Controller -  Just to show an example of what i'm returning:

```
public function actionFilter() {
$by= $_POST['test'];
$string = "";
if ($by == 1) {
return $string = self::searchPendingEvent();  
}}

public function searchPendingEvent() {
    $query = Event::findBySql("Select * from dot_events where (dot_event_to_user =" . Yii::$app->user->id . " "
                    . "and dot_event_type = 1 and dot_event_completed = 0) or ("
                    . "dot_event_type = 4 and dot_event_to_user =" . Yii::$app->user->id . " and dot_event_completed = 0)"
                    . " order by dot_datecreate DESC")->asArray()->all();


    $string = "";
    if ($query == null) {
        $string .="Nothing to show :(";
    } else {

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($query); $i++) {

            $string.= self::formatEvent($query[$i]['dot_event_id']);
        }
    }

    return $string;
}

public function formatEvent($id) {

if ($model['dot_event_type'] == 1 && $model['dot_event_to_user'] == Yii::$app->user->id) {
        $string .= "<p class='text-primary text-right p1'>" . Functions::xTimeAgo($model['dot_datecreate'], date("c", time())) . "</p>";
        $string .="<div class='well'>";
        $string .="<p class='lead text-left text-primary'>";
        $string .= "<img class='img-circle' height='50' width='50' src='" . Yii::$app->request->baseUrl . "/img/user/" . $model['dot_event_to_user'] . ".png' alt='Image Missing'>";
        $string .=Html::a("You", ['user/profile']);
        $string .="</p>";
        $string .="<p class='text-left'>requested " . Html::a($profile[0]['full_name']);
        $string .="to trade " . Html::a($tradeE['dot_cr_dots'] . " pts", ['dashboard/index']) . " from company ";
        $string .=$company['dot_com_name'] . " for company" . $companyE['dot_com_name'];
        $string .="</p>";
        $string .="</div>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirect starts at this line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",document.location.href="filter?by="+str,true);
```

after asignment

```
document.location.href="filter?by="+str
```

I thinks there is mistake or typo. Try this:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",document.location.href+"/filter?by="+str,true);
```

Or with jQuery ( http://api.jquery.com/load/ ):

```
function showUser(str) {
  $( "#transactions" ).load( "test.php", { "by": str } );
}
```

where test.php - url where from you get data for your #transactions block

UPD:
remove your `<script>...</script>` in head

```
<?=Html::dropDownList(
    'test', //name
    'b', //select
    ['' => 'Select Filter...', '1' => 'Exchanging Now', '2' => 'Last Exchanged', '3' => 'Last Offered', '4' => 'Last Discounted', '5' => 'Last Recieved', '6' => 'View All'],
    ['onchange'=> 'showUser(this.value)'])
  ?>
  <?php
  use yii\web\View;
  $this->registerJs('
  function showUser(str) {
      $( "#transactions" ).load( "dashboard/filter", { "by": str } );
  }', View::POS_END);
  ?>
```

So now your js code positioned after connecting jQuery file.

Comment: Hello, that didn't work. 

    Not Found
    The requested URL /filter was not found on this server.

It returns the url= Localhost/filter

Comment: "In my controller I'm returning a string." What the name of Controller and Action where you should get data for #transactions div ?

Comment: sorry for late reply. My controller is dashboard/filter.
instead of "xmlhttp.open..." I must put function "showUser(str) {
  $( "#transactions" ).load( "dashboard/filter", { "by": str } );
}" ? Thanks

Comment: humm, still not working... Just stand still, don't do nothing

Comment: it's because jQuery is declared at end of html. So $( "#transactions" ) selectors in HEAD section won't work. Updated answer with working variant.

Comment: Well, can't make it work. It looks like don't accept the jQuery code don't know why. I tried a new approach with pjax. With a link <a> link I can make it work, I only have to change the from the attribute formSelector to linkSelector. But with the form don't work. It redirects to another page with the results. Can you help me on this way?
I updated the question

Comment: Finally got it working, I edited your answer if you don't mind :) Thanks again for all the help and sorry for the trouble.